# Abnormality when drawing a view inside of a stack view

Tags: swift, uiview, uistackview

Exploring stackviews I've ran into a problem of incorrect representation if views inside of it. So, to make a long story short...
I've made a custom checkbox:

```
class CheckBox: UIView, CheckBoxProtocol {

required init(frame: CGRect, color: UIColor) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    self.layer.borderWidth = 5
    self.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
    self.addSubview(checkmark)
    checkmark.tintColor = color
    
    
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toggle))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

var isChecked = true

lazy var checkmark: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height))
    
    imageView.isHidden = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark")
    
    return imageView
}()

@objc func toggle() {
    self.isChecked.toggle()
    self.checkmark.isHidden = !self.isChecked
}
```

In the Controller, when I add this view to the subviews it looks fairly normal and works as it should work (check-uncheck)

However when I add checkbox to the stackview it looses its visible frame and its functionality (does not check-uncheck) - you can see it on the screenshot

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EAEj.png)

Here is the code from the ViewController:

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    
    self.view.addSubview(stackView)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}

lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 0, height: 0))
    
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.spacing = 50
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    [redCheckbox,
     greenCheckbox,
     blackCheckbox,
     greyCheckbox,
     brownCheckbox,
     yellowCheckbox,
     purpleCheckbox,
     orangeCheckbox].forEach {stackView.addArrangedSubview($0)} 
    
    return stackView
}()

private let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)

lazy var redCheckbox: CheckBox = {
    let colorFactory = CardViewFactory()
    let color = colorFactory.getViewColor(modelColor: CardColor.red)
    let checkbox = CheckBox(frame: frame, color: color)
    
    return checkbox
}()

lazy var greenCheckbox: CheckBox = {
    let colorFactory = CardViewFactory()
    let color = colorFactory.getViewColor(modelColor: CardColor.green)
    let checkbox = CheckBox(frame: frame, color: color)
    
    return checkbox
}()

lazy var blackCheckbox: CheckBox = {
    let colorFactory = CardViewFactory()
    let color = colorFactory.getViewColor(modelColor: CardColor.black)
    let checkbox = CheckBox(frame: frame, color: color)
    
    return checkbox
}()

lazy var greyCheckbox: CheckBox = {
    let colorFactory = CardViewFactory()
    let color = colorFactory.getViewColor(modelColor: CardColor.grey)
    let checkbox = CheckBox(frame: frame, color: color)
    
    return checkbox
}()

lazy var brownCheckbox: CheckBox = {
    let colorFactory = CardViewFactory()
    let color = colorFactory.getViewColor(modelColor: CardColor.brown)
    let checkbox = CheckBox(frame: frame, color: color)
    
    return checkbox
}()

lazy var yellowCheckbox: CheckBox = {
    let colorFactory = CardViewFactory()
    let color = colorFactory.getViewColor(modelColor: CardColor.yellow)
    let checkbox = CheckBox(frame: frame, color: color)
    
    return checkbox
}()

lazy var purpleCheckbox: CheckBox = {
    let colorFactory = CardViewFactory()
    let color = colorFactory.getViewColor(modelColor: CardColor.purple)
    let checkbox = CheckBox(frame: frame, color: color)
    
    return checkbox
}()

lazy var orangeCheckbox: CheckBox = {
    let colorFactory = CardViewFactory()
    let color = colorFactory.getViewColor(modelColor: CardColor.orange)
    let checkbox = CheckBox(frame: frame, color: color)
    
    return checkbox
}()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because we're working with the **lazy** property and its life cycle can be a little different. Let's set constraints after the view has loaded. What I would suggest to do:

1. For each checkbox, change the frame to zero:

   ```
    lazy var orangeCheckbox: CheckBox = {
       let colorFactory = CardViewFactory()
       let color = colorFactory.getViewColor(modelColor: CardColor.orange)
       let checkbox = CheckBox(frame: .zero, color: colorFactory)
       checkbox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       return checkbox
    }()
   ```
2. Do the same to the stackView:

   ```
    lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
       let stackView = UIStackView(frame: .zero)
       stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       stackView.axis = .horizontal
       stackView.spacing = 5
       stackView.alignment = .fill
       stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
       [redCheckbox,
        greenCheckbox,
        blackCheckbox,
        greyCheckbox,
        brownCheckbox,
        yellowCheckbox,
        purpleCheckbox,
        orangeCheckbox].forEach {stackView.addArrangedSubview($0)}

       return stackView
    }()
   ```
3. Add some constraints on viewDidLoad:

   ```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       view.backgroundColor = .white
       view.addSubview(stackView)

       stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
       stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
       stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
       stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

       [redCheckbox,
        greenCheckbox,
        blackCheckbox,
        greyCheckbox,
        brownCheckbox,
        yellowCheckbox,
        purpleCheckbox,
        orangeCheckbox].forEach {
           $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
           $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
       }
    }
   ```

What you can do to the image inside the checkBox to work fine:

1. translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   ```
    lazy var checkmark: UIImageView = {
       let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
       imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       imageView.isHidden = false
       imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
       imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark")
       return imageView
    }()
   ```
2. on your required init:

   ```
    required init(frame: CGRect, color: UIColor) {
       super.init(frame: frame)

       self.layer.borderWidth = 5
       self.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
       self.addSubview(checkmark)
       checkmark.tintColor = color

       checkmark.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
       checkmark.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
       checkmark.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
       checkmark.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true

       let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toggle))
       self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
       setNeedsDisplay()
    }
   ```

Comment: Your solution solved my problem. How does it work under the hood? Is it all about constraints?

Comment: Totally about constraints, but mainly because they're inside a stack view. I tested the checkbox view outside the stack, and it worked nice. 
But you're working with a lazy var inside a stack. It was set after you're used it, and the layer inside the stack didn't understood what size it could assume. 
When building views programmatically, make sure that you have constraints and that translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is set to false.

More about view code:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/8/2/building-a-uikit-user-interface-programmatically

Comment: Thank you! I will be more attentive to that next time

Answer (score 0):

To offer some additional info...

You can save yourself a **lot** of duplicate coding.

Take a look at this...

First, slight modifications to your `Checkbox` class:

```
class CheckBox: UIView {//, CheckBoxProtocol {
    
    var checkmark: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "checkmark")
        return imageView
    }()
    
    var isChecked = true {
        didSet {
            checkmark.isHidden = !isChecked
        }
    }
    
    required init(frame: CGRect, color: UIColor) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit(color)
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit(.white)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit(.white)
    }
    
    func commonInit(_ color: UIColor) {
        
        self.layer.borderWidth = 5
        self.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor

        self.addSubview(checkmark)
        checkmark.tintColor = color
        
        checkmark.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain image view to all 4 sides
            checkmark.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            checkmark.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            checkmark.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            checkmark.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toggle))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
    
    @objc func toggle() {
        self.isChecked.toggle()
    }

}
```

We've used auto-layout to keep the image view the same size as the view itself.

And, by implementing the `var isChecked` block we have a more "automated" way of setting the image view's hidden state.

In addition, we can now get the "state" of the checkbox in the controller like this:

```
if thisCheckBox.isChecked {
    // do something
}
```

Now the view controller... we'll define an array of colors, loop through them to create the CheckBox objects, and add them to the stack view:

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        // desired spacing
        stackView.spacing = 12
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        return stackView
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        self.view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // stack view Top constraint
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 150.0),
            // centered horizontally
            stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            // explicit Height
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0),
        ])
    
        let colors: [UIColor] = [
            .red, .green, .black, .gray,
            .brown, .yellow, .purple, .orange,
        ]

        // loop through the colors, creating a new
        //  CheckBox object for each color
        //  and add it to the stack view
        colors.forEach { c in
            let checkbox = CheckBox(frame: .zero, color: c)
            // 1:1 aspect ratio
            checkbox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkbox.heightAnchor).isActive = true
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(checkbox)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

As you can see, we've eliminated the need for all of the individual

```
lazy var redCheckbox: CheckBox = { ...
lazy var greenCheckbox: CheckBox = { ...
// etc
```

code blocks.